# Failed to connect Keycloak to MySQL via docker-compose due to SSL issues

Tags: mysql, ssl, docker-compose, keycloak

I am using MySQL 5.7 and Keycloak 9.0.3's docker images via docker-compose. However, Keycloak failed to bootstrap since it cannot connect to MySQL due to SSL issues.

```
keycloak_1        | 06:52:58,884 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) Thu Apr 16 06:52:58 GMT 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

I checked other questions and appended `JBDC_PARAMS: 'useSSL=false'` in my `docker-compose.yml` but it didn't work either. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
version: '3'

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

services:
  keycloak_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:9.0.3
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: keycloak_mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: Password0!
      JBDC_PARAMS: 'useSSL=false'
    ports:
      - 9099:8080
    depends_on:
      - keycloak_mysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there is a typo? Try changing `JBDC_PARAMS`to `JDBC_PARAMS`and see if it works